# Multiple table join with condition from one table

Tags: sql, select, left-join

I apologize in advance if something like this has already been discussed elsewhere, but if it has, I was unable to find it (I'm not even sure how to search such a thing). I'm trying to join two tables, "employees" and "leave." I want to list every employee from the "employees" table AND populate the report with leave data from the "leave" table where the 'leave date' (bdate column in the leave table) is greater than January 1st, 2014 (or current year). The problem is that not every employee has leave data, so I'm finding that a normal join only fetches data from those employees who actually have leave data. I think what I want is a left join, but I'm only getting records from both tables where there is actually data for that employee in both tables (hope that makes sense).

```
Select bunch_of_columns, leave.bdate, SUM(leave.Vhours) as TotalVacationHours, SUM(leave.shours) as TotalSickHours
from employees 
left join leave on employees.id=leave.id
where employees.user_active ='1' AND leave.BDate >= '2014-01-01'
group by employees.id
Order by employees.user_last
```

This produces ONE record of an individual who has a leave record after "2014-01-01." I want a complete list of employee records from the employee table with available data from the leave table (and blank if there is none) where the "bdate" column in the leave table is greater than new years day.

I want this:

```
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
|ID   | Name     | Vacation Hrs  | Sick Hrs      | Date         |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
|   1 | Bob      | 5             | 8             | 2014-01-01   |
|   2 | Lucy     | NULL          | NULL          | NULL         |
|   3 | Jerry    | NULL          | NULL          | NULL         |
|   4 | Dieter   | 3             | 5             | 2014-01-08   |
|   5 | Sprockets| NULL          | NULL          | NULL         |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Not this:

```
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| row | Name     | Vacation Hrs  | Sick Hrs      | Date         |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
|   1 | Bob      | 5             | 8             | 2014-01-01   |
|   4 | Dieter   | 3             | 5             | 2014-01-08   |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of your `WHERE` condition.

```
leave.BDate >= '2014-01-01'
```

If you do a `LEFT JOIN` and then filter a column in the right table to something that can't be `NULL`, it's equivalent to doing an `INNER JOIN`.

If there's no leave date then the record doesn't fit the criteria. You should check instead that:

```
(leave.BDate >= '2014-01-01' OR leave.BDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Easy for you to say! I don't know why that didn't occur to me.  Thank you so much, OGHaza and DRapp! That works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

another way to write it (as pointed out by OGHaza) is apply the date condition to the JOIN portion

```
Select 
      bunch_of_columns, 
      leave.bdate, 
      COALESCE( SUM(leave.Vhours), 0 ) as TotalVacationHours, 
      COALESCE( SUM(leave.shours), 0 ) as TotalSickHours
   from 
      employees 
         left join leave 
            on employees.id=leave.id
            AND leave.BDate >= '2014-01-01'
   where 
      employees.user_active ='1' 
   group by 
      employees.id
   Order by 
      employees.user_last
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, that's exactly how I'd do it in practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Full Outer Join for such condition.

From MSDN

The full outer join or full join returns all rows from both tables, matching up the rows wherever a match can be made and placing NULLs in the places where no matching row exists.